# Android Bluetooth deserialization ObjectNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluecove

Well I have some trouble to deserialize  my class  over bluetooth. From pc to android device im Using the bluecove snapshot 2.1.1 library on my pc application My inputstream on android  does receive bytes because as soon I send some data to my ouputstream my android application crash.
So here my stack trace. Also, the bluetooth socket is working since I can send integers into bytes on the pc

```
W/System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bluetooth.LiteProject
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:2258)
W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1641)
W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:657)
W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1782)
W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:761)
W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
W/System.err:     at com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting.BluetoothThreadClasses.BluetoothDataShare.deserialize(BluetoothDataShare.java:121)
W/System.err:     at com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:96)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5714)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10926)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22589)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "bluetooth.LiteProject" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-25.0.0_733f073c18693e37682f4ac22b5f541d6f65a521-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-25.0.0_9bc67552422813c99b6458ea8770395016890bfd-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-25.0.0_5030af852f549789ae15eb264dc11320e23256e8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-25.0.0_4a2c66133c72c8cb335db37fa043de6026539626-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-25.0.0_3a303aa6f7e828e43c1336863ca83eefc55642dc-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-25.0.0_2d05349ce99bb610027ae1a1f205e7ff481c80ea-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-vector-drawable-25.0.0_93d794c274330c4bac9e23b24b0692ce4a48b160-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-v4-25.0.0_bf3767cfe44655d3a165ffe94a66d5d9feaa2a26-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-media-compat-25.0.0_8edae4c59f3b3f76c9b225952262e5bc47b157df-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-fragment-25.0.0_f7d3af020703d4b4bd21e04d132251937de287d4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-core-utils-25.0.0_86f6e8f7e9b82e3cd1e20da88591291ea705ca15-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-core-ui-25.0.0_6d54f4432204da9a7699fadec1a26048490d7085-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-compat-25.0.0_95ad1fee5438892c0a020310eab8df2a9dced983-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-appcompat-v7-25.0.0_44eb0fc3008faa9171481a9770d2142ed7ee8ee5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-animated-vector-drawable-25.0.0_788179e51b8915f8f95cd660c0d2ba6af7650941-classes.dex"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
W/System.err:     at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:90)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
W/System.err:   ... 21 more
W/System.err:   Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "bluetooth.LiteProject" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
W/System.err:       ... 22 more
W/System.err:       Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "bluetooth.LiteProject" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-25.0.0_733f073c18693e37682f4ac22b5f541d6f65a521-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-25.0.0_9bc67552422813c99b6458ea8770395016890bfd-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-25.0.0_5030af852f549789ae15eb264dc11320e23256e8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-25.0.0_4a2c66133c72c8cb335db37fa043de6026539626-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-25.0.0_3a303aa6f7e828e43c1336863ca83eefc55642dc-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-25.0.0_2d05349ce99bb610027ae1a1f205e7ff481c80ea-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-vector-drawable-25.0.0_93d794c274330c4bac9e23b24b0692ce4a48b160-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-v4-25.0.0_bf3767cfe44655d3a165ffe94a66d5d9feaa2a26-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-media-compat-25.0.0_8edae4c59f3b3f76c9b225952262e5bc47b157df-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-fragment-25.0.0_f7d3af020703d4b4bd21e04d132251937de287d4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-core-utils-25.0.0_86f6e8f7e9b82e3cd1e20da88591291ea705ca15-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-core-ui-25.0.0_6d54f4432204da9a7699fadec1a26048490d7085-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-compat-25.0.0_95ad1fee5438892c0a020310eab8df2a9dced983-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-appcompat-v7-25.0.0_44eb0fc3008faa9171481a9770d2142ed7ee8ee5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-animated-vector-drawable-25.0.0_788179e51b8915f8f95cd660c0d2ba6af7650941-classes.dex"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.ihat3i.androidtesting-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
W/System.err:     at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:90)
W/System.err:     at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:62)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
W/System.err:           ... 23 more
W/System.err:           Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bluetooth.LiteProject
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
W/System.err:               ... 24 more
W/System.err:           Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

here in my code from android where I receive the Object and deserialize it

```
public class BluetoothDataShare extends Thread {
 private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private static InputStream mmInStream;
        private static  OutputStream mmOutStream ;
        public static LiteProject lite = null;

public BluetoothDataShare(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created");    
            }    
            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;   

        }


    public static LiteProject deserialize() {

        ObjectInputStream o = null;
        LiteProject liteProject = null;
        try {
            o = new ObjectInputStream(mmInStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            liteProject = (LiteProject) o.readObject();
            o.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
        return  liteProject;
    }    


    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close of connect socket failed");
            }
        }
}
```

this is the code where I serialize on the pc

```
public static byte[] serialize(LiteProject liteProject){
        ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try(ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b)){
        o.writeObject(liteProject);

        }catch(IOException ex ){}
        return b.toByteArray();            
    }
```

this is where the outputStream is initialized

```
private StreamConnection mConnection;

    // Constant that indicate command from devices
    private static final int EXIT_CMD = -1;
    private static final int SWIPE_RIGHT = 1;
    private static final int SWIPE_LEFT = 2;
    public static OutputStream outputStream;

    public ProcessConnectionThread(StreamConnection connection)
    {
        mConnection = connection;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {

            // prepare to receive data
            InputStream inputStream = mConnection.openInputStream();
            outputStream = mConnection.openOutputStream();

            System.out.println("waiting for input");

            while (true) {

                int command = inputStream.read();

                if (command == EXIT_CMD)
                {
                    System.out.println("finish process");
                    break;
                }

                processCommand(command);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

this is where the outputstream send the serialized object to the android device

```
    if(isSelected()){
    OutputStream outputStream = ProcessConnectionThread.outputStream;

    if(outputStream != null){
        Project project = projects.get(selectedIndex());
        LiteProject liteProject = new LiteProject(project);
        outputStream.write(ProjectMethods.serialize());
```

And finally this is the LiteProject class that are the same on both side (pc and android)

```
public class LiteProject implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;
    private int slideCount;
    private String[] notes;
    private int[] animationsCount;
    private String name;

    public LiteProject(Project project){
        slideCount =  project.getSlideCount();
        notes = project.notes;
        name = project.getName();       
    }
    public String getName(){return name;}
```